# Python script stops with no error message

Tags: python, pymupdf

I am running quite a large script working through some pds documents using pymupdf, when i encounter an error no error message appear, the scrpt just stops running. When i trace the execution of the script it stops at quite random places. 2 times it stopped on a simple return function that just returns som variables (dicts containing strings and integers). and other times it stopped at:

```
try:
  test = spage.get_text('blocks')
except:
  pass
```

So i dont understand why it stops at different times when i run through it (The exact same documents each time) and most importantly why it stops even though the error is within an try-except clause. and why it doesnt display the error when the error is not within a try-except clause?

I have suspected it might be memory releated since the error happens at different places, but memory seems fine and stable

Comment: `except: pass` is never a good idea if you want to find a problem.

Comment: well the facts that it encounters an error in itself is fine, the problem is that it stops when it does instead of "passing". The particular error that is provided in the try-except i included is just recursion depth tree.

Comment: @Nursk - as I already wrote on the home page: whether there is a bug or an unrecoverable problem in the file, it cannot be solved without that file. Please do submit it on the Github homepage of the pakage.